# How to get a span element to show a value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file with a .js file that has the javascript.

In the HTML file I have `<p>Total Estimate: <span id= "estimate"></span></p>`

But nothing shows up when opened in a browser. This is a practice that you are supposed to go along with in my textbook and as far as I can see, I am doing it correctly. I am getting an error in the JS that says
ERROR:'document' is not defined.[no-undef]
This is where ever document is seen in the JS.

This is my JS code. Is there a problem I don't see?

```
// global variables
var photographerCost = 0;
var totalCost = 0;
var memoryBook = false;
var reproductionRights = false;
// calculates all costs based on staff and adds to total cost
function calcStaff() {
    var num = document.getElementById("photognum");
    var hrs = document.getElementById("photoghrs");
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
    totalCost -= photographerCost;
    photographerCost = num.value * 100 * hrs.value + distance.value * num.value;
    totalCost += photographerCost;
    document.getElementById("estimate") .innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
// adds/subtracts cost of memory book from total cost
function toggleMembook() {
    (document.getElementById("membook") .checked === false) ?
        totalCost -= 250 : totalCost + 250;
    document.getElementById("estimate") .innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
// ads/subtracts cost of reproduction rights from total cost
function toggleRights() {
    (document.getElementById('reprodrights') .checked === false) ?
        totalCost -= 1250 : totalCost += 1250;
    document.getElementById("estimate") .innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
// sets all form field values to defaults
function resetForm()    {
document.getElementById ("photognum") .value = 1;
document.getElementById ("photoghrs") .value =2;
document.getElementById ("membook") .checked = memoryBook;
document.getElementById ("reprodrights") .checked = reproductionRights;
document.getElementById ("distance") .value = 0;
calcStaff();
createEventListeners();
}
// creates event listeners
function createEventListeners() {
document.getElementById("photognum") .addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);   
document.getElementById("photoghrs") .addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
document.getElementById("membook") .addEventListener("change", toggleMembook, false);
document.getElementById("reprodrights") .addEventListener("change", toggleRights, false);
document.getElementById("distance") .addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
}
// resets form when page is reloaded
document.addEventListener("load", resetForm, false);
```

Below is HTML

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography - Estimate</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 999px)" href="fthand.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)" href="fantrick.css" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftie.css" />
   <![endif]-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+Bedfort' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
   <div id="container">
      <header>
         <h1>
            <img src="images/ftlogo.png" alt="Fan Trick Fine Art Photography" title="" />
         </h1>
      </header>

      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="currentpage"><a href="#">estimate</a></li>
            <li><a href="digital.htm">Digital 101</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
        
      <article>
         <h2>Estimate</h2>
         <p>Our experienced, professional photography team is available to capture memories of your wedding, celebration, or other special event.</p>
         <p>Choose the custom options that fit your needs:</p>
         <form id="estimateform">
            <fieldset>
               <legend><span>Photography</span></legend>
               <input type="number" min="0" max="4" id="photognum" value="1" />
               <label for="photognum">
                  <p># of photographers (1&#8209;4)</p>
                  <p>$100/hr</p>
               </label>

               <input type="number" min="2" id="photoghrs" value="2" />
               <label for="photoghrs">
                  <p># of hours to photograph (minimum&nbsp;2)</p>
               </label>

               <input type="checkbox" id="membook" />
               <label for="membook">
                  <p>Memory book</p>
                  <p>$250</p>
               </label>

               <input type="checkbox" id="reprodrights" />
               <label for="reprodrights">
                  <p>Reproduction rights for all photos</p>
                  <p>$1250</p>
               </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
               <legend><span>Travel</span></legend>
               <input type="number" id="distance" value="0" />
               <label for="distance">
                  <p>Event distance from Austin, TX</p>
                  <p>$1/mi per photographer</p>
               </label>
            </fieldset>
         </form>
      </article>
      <aside>
         <p>Total Estimate: <span id= "estimate"></span></p>
      </aside>
      <footer>
         <p>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography &bull; Austin, Texas</p>
      </footer>
   </div>
    <script src="ft.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do any errors or other messages appear in the JS console?

Comment: Please share the contents of the HTML file as well.

Comment: Yea, this error is the one that comes up.        ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]  where ever document is used.

Comment: I have now added the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below

```js
function calcStaff() {
    var num = document.getElementById("photognum");
    var hrs = document.getElementById("photoghrs");
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
    totalCost -= photographerCost;
    //You need use Number to change all value
    //fix
      photographerCost = Number(num.value) * 100 * Number(hrs.value) + Number(distance.value) * Number(num.value);
    //============//
    //This code systax not support
    //photographerCost = num.value * 100 * hrs.value + distance.value * num.value;
    totalCost += photographerCost;
    document.getElementById("estimate") .innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

Comment: I tried using this in place but it did not help. For some reason the form will reset properly when the page is refreshed but, there is never a display of the total when you adjust numbers on the form, my textbook states that it should.